# Open Graph API: Find out if user is application administrator

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

How can I see if a user is an administrator for the facebook application that I am using to make the API call.

Something like https://graph.facebook.com/{userId}/applications or https://graph.facebook.com/{applicationId}/administrators (these does not work)

Comment: You should read the docs, instead of just guessing. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#roles

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I tried but could not find the information I searched for, hence the question here.

Calling GET https://graph.facebook.com/123applicationId/roles in Graph API Explorer with an access_token for the application (selected from the dropdown) gives me the error:

    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported operation",
        "type": "FacebookApiException",
        "code": 100
      }
    }

Which is strange since the documentation tells me to call that url with an application access token.

Comment: It turned out that the access token I got when selecting my application from the dropdown was the wrong one. I got the correct access_token by calling GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

Answer (score 1):

You can attack this at two ways:

1. Try calling /{userId}/accounts and see if the application id is under the results. You need to make sure you get the 'manage_pages' permission from the user for this to work.
2. Try calling graph.facebook.com/{applicationId}/administrators. In order to do this, you need to use an access token that acts as the application. You can get the access token from the same call in the above solution, /{userId}/accounts. Then check if the user exists in these results.